# Access right on synonym and underlying table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, privileges, synonym

1/ How are privileges on synonyms and underlying objects related ? If one has rights on synonym, would he automatically has rights on the table and vice versa ?

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views003.htm) says

> When you grant object privileges on a synonym, you are really granting
>   privileges on the underlying object, and the synonym is acting only as
>   an alias for the object in the GRANT statement

which means privilege on synonym is enough. That will bypass table privilege.

[Another source](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2161756?start=0&tstart=0) says that access right on table is enough and synonym privilege has no meaning.

Does it mean either privilege on the synonym or the underlying table is enough ?

2/ Is the behavior the same for private and public synonym. I haven't really seen an example of granting privileges on synonyms for a user to "see/access". How to grant privilege on private synonyms to a user ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the Oracle docs and the message you referred to say exactly the same thing. Privileges are not granted on a synonym. When you attempt to grant privileges on a synonym the database actually performs the grant on the object referred to by the synonym. Thus, it makes no difference if the synonym is public or private because the actual grant is made on the object referred to by the synonym.

Best of luck.

### EDIT

Let's demonstrate what happens:

```
-- Logged in as user BOB2

CREATE TABLE RPJ_TEST (N NUMBER);

SELECT *
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RPJ_TEST';

-- the above statement returns no rows

CREATE SYNONYM RPJ_TEST_SYN  -- create synonym
  FOR RPJ_TEST;

SELECT *
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RPJ_TEST';

-- the above statement returns no rows

GRANT SELECT ON RPJ_TEST TO BOB;  -- grant on table

SELECT *
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RPJ_TEST';

-- the above statement returns
GRANTEE     OWNER   TABLE_NAME  GRANTOR PRIVILEGE   GRANTABLE  HIERARCHY
BOB         BOB2    RPJ_TEST    BOB2    SELECT      NO         NO

GRANT UPDATE ON RPJ_TEST_SYN TO BOB2;  -- grant "on synonym" actually performs grant on table

SELECT *
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RPJ_TEST';

GRANTEE     OWNER  TABLE_NAME   GRANTOR  PRIVILEGE GRANTABLE  HIERARCHY
BOB         BOB2   RPJ_TEST     BOB2     SELECT    NO         NO
BOB         BOB2   RPJ_TEST     BOB2     UPDATE    NO         NO
```

Note that after the grant on the synonym RPJ_TEST_SYN the privileges granted on the table referred to by the synonym had been changed.

Comment: Great answer. In that case what is the real difference between public and private synonym if it's only the underlying object that matters ? By saying "public synonym is accesible by everyone" does it mean everyone now have access to the underlying object when its synonym is declared as public ?

Comment: @Kenny: a synonym is just a short-hand way to get at something, so that instead of typing `LONG_WINDED_SCHEMA_NAME.NAME_OF_FRQNTLY_ACCESSED_TABLE` you can just type the name of the synonym, e.g. `FREQUENT_TABLE`. Access to the underlying object is still subject to whatever GRANTs have been issued.

Comment: So came my question of the difference between private and public synonym in that case. If synonym is nothing but an invisible veil that everyones just walk through in, and rights on underlying objects are what count, then how do they differ and what does it mean by "public synonym is accesible by everyone" ?

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle Doc "A public synonym is owned by the special user group named PUBLIC and is accessible to every user in a database. A private synonym is contained in the schema of a specific user and available only to the user and to grantees for the underlying object."

With a public synonym PUBS on TABLE X of Schema B, User A can access User B's table X. With a private synonym PVTS on TABLE Y of Schema B, User A cannot access User B's table Y unless access is granted explicitly as mentioned above.

Check [OracleDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views003.htm)

Comment: Does it mean creating a public synonym S to a table T will grant everyone every rights on T ?

Comment: Creating synonyms does not grant privileges. Synonyms help maintain code and objects privileges. Say there are two things cot and lamp. Cot belongs to Mr. A. Lamp belongs to Mr. B. Say bed is the private synonym of cot and light is the public synonym of lamp. Say A has the right to turn off B's lamp and B has the right to fold A's cot. Now A can say turn off B's lamp or turn off light. But B cannot say fold bed. B has to say A's Bed or A's cot. Private synonyms need qualification by schema. But public synonyms need no schema qualification. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: It did answer my question thanks. "Everyone sees" only means no schema reference needed, This has nothing to do with the rights on underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:-
Suppose there is a table tab1 defined in abc_owner schema and its synonym is created in abc_user schema, then:-

Running a grant like this in the abc_user schema:-

```
GRANT SELECT  ON tab1  TO def_owner;
```

might succeed or fail depending on the grants that abc_user has over the objects in abc_owner.
If it has only select grants, the above query will fail.
And then you will have to do it in the owner schema itself.